# ExternalProject_Add doesn't install the Release configuration of the project

Tags: cmake, external-project

**EDIT:** I have found a probable cause but I do not understand why: the last line in the below script `Project(Externals)` when removed fixes my issue. So the question now why??

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

include(ExternalProject)

MACRO(EXTERNAL_DEF aNewTargetName aPathToSource)
  ExternalProject_Add(
    ${aNewTargetName}
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    SOURCE_DIR ${aPathToSource}

    TMP_DIR      "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/tmp/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
    DOWNLOAD_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/src/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
    BINARY_DIR   "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/src/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/${aNewTargetName}-build"
    STAMP_DIR    "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/src/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/${aNewTargetName}-stamp"
    CMAKE_ARGS
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
      --debug-output
    BUILD_COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build
      "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/src/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/${aNewTargetName}-build" --config "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
    #INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}"
    )
ENDMACRO()

get_filename_component(zlibAbsPath "./zlib" ABSOLUTE)
EXTERNAL_DEF(zlib_external ${zlibAbsPath})
Project(Externals)
```

I invoke cmake on the above CMakeLists.txt file with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` set to let's say *"d:\externals"* and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` set to *"Release"*

**Expectation:**
I would expect only the *Release* configuration to get built. And after it gets built I would expect it to get installed in `D:\externals\bin\zlib.dll`.

**Problem:**
In reality, ExternalProject_Add builds both a *Debug* and a *Release*, and installs the debug version of the dll in `D:\externals\bin\zlibd.dll`

Isn't my build script correct? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
some more info. I just noticed. In the generated D:\externals\src\Release\zlib_external-build\zlib.sln, the INSTALL target is not selected to build at all. If I check it to build for the Release configuration then hit "Build" from visual studio, the INSTALL target builds and installs the files where I expect them. I have no idea what's going on...

Answer (score 4):

[CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE only work with  single-configuration projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842218/how-to-use-cmake-externalproject-add-or-alternatives-in-a-cross-platform-way)

you can change to:

```
  BUILD_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    --build .
    --target install
    --config Release
  BUILD_ALWAYS 1
```

Answer (score -3):

Use DCMAKE_CFG_INTDIR variable.

```
...
CMAKE_ARGS
    ...
    -DCMAKE_CFG_INTDIR=Release
```

Comment: From the docs of [`CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR): `This variable is read-only. Setting it is undefined behavior.`.