# build cmake ExternalProject with gradle

Tags: gradle, cmake

I am trying to use an existing native library as part of an android project. I followed instructions about adding C and C++ Code to a project for android studio. I got to the point where I have a functioning CMakeLists.txt file (tested independently) and I've instructed gradle to use it to compile the native code.

The library I'm using uses make so I use ExternalProject_Add to instruct cmake how to compile it. Here is the relevant code:

```
ExternalProject_Add(foo
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libfoo
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libfoo/configure
        --host=arm-linux-androideabi
    BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
    INSTALL_COMMAND true)
```

This is the relevant part of the build.gradle for the module:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path '../cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew assembleDebug`, the external project is not compiled. After adding an executable (named `bar`) that depends on `foo` in cmake, the configure step runs but the build step doesn't. I modified the code of the library so that compilation would fail, but gradle returns success anyway).

Here are the last lines of the output of `./gradlew assembleDebug` after these changes.

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
[6/10] Performing build step for 'foo'
[7/10] Performing install step for 'foo'
[8/10] Completed 'foo'
[9/10] Building C object CMakeFiles/bar.dir/bar.c.o
[10/10] Linking C executable bar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 18s
```

Any ideas what is happening? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using gradle 4.1 and cmake 3.6.

Comment: Can you add `LOG_BUILD ON` to your ExternalProject_Add ?
also did you wrap in an imported target the result of the build to consume it in `bar` ?

Answer (score 1):

you should use [`BUILD_IN_SOURCE ON`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) otherwise your `BINARY_DIR` is somewhere else so `make` do nothing IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, this was the reason nothing happened while building. However I still need the fictional executable `bar` to make gradle do the steps for the external target.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47636956/192373. You don't need fictional executables. You do need two separate targets, though.

```
add_library(foolib SHARED IMPORTED)
add_dependencies(foolib foo)
set_target_properties(foolib IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libfoo/…/libfoo.so)
```

You don't necessarily need `BUILD_IN_SOURCE ON`, better set `BINARY_DIR` somewhere in `build/intermediates`, and pass the same to `make`.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I'm struggling here. So "foo" here comes from `ExternalProject_Add(foo ...`, correct? In my case, this is still not running the build (the configure step is fine though). However, my configure step writes files in `.cxx` and not in `build/intermediates`. Is that relevant? It does set `-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to `build/intermediates`, though.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to why the configure step is fine, but then gradle somehow does not run `ninja -C path_to_builddir`

Comment: I don't understand what files your configuration step writes in `.cxx`. The bottom line of my approach is that the external build (`make` in the case of original question) is not used *as is* by CMake that is coordinated with Gradle, but an extra `IMPORTED` step is introduced which takes care of all dependencies. As for your continuation, why should Gradle run `ninja`?

Comment: That's what it does automatically. I am building for Android, and it sets stuff like the toolchain etc. And `-GNinja`.

Comment: I didn't express myself well. What I tried to say, if Gradle and CMake find that the build is not necessary, they won't start `ninja`.

Comment: Right. I'm guessing that Gradle would run `cmake --build [...]` (which runs ninja), and when I run `cmake --build [...]` manually, it works (even without your additional target "foolib"). So it feels like Gradle does not run it somehow (even when I add your foolib target)... But I don't understand why and I don't know how to see it.

Comment: Most likely your **foolib** is not correctly wired into the setup.

Comment: Hmm I opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75115285/cmake-imported-library-not-included-in-gradle-output