# CMake ExternalProject superbuild isn't executed with Android NDK

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Related to: [build cmake ExternalProject with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098718/build-cmake-externalproject-with-gradle)

I'm trying to port an existing C++ project to Android (using Android Studio 3.0.1). The C++ project depends on a few other C++ packages. Since they all need to be cross-compiled for Android, I'm trying to execute a superbuild using CMake's [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/ExternalProject.html) (see a non-Android example [here](https://github.com/wngreene/external_project_test)).

Calling `<package>/gradlew assembleRelease` should (AFAIK) compile everything, but it appears to only execute the CMake configuration step and doesn't actually call `ninja` to execute the build step, meaning none of the ExternalProjects are downloaded or built. In order to actually download and compile the ExternalProjects, I need navigate to `<package>/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/<BUILD_TYPE>/<ABI>` and manually call `ninja`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my top-level CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include(ExternalProject)

if (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install)
endif ()

# Forward Android CMake cross compile args to ExternalProject.
set(ANDROID_CMAKE_ARGS
  -DANDROID_ABI=${ANDROID_ABI}
  -DANDROID_PLATFORM=${ANDROID_PLATFORM}
  -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
  -DANDROID_NDK=${ANDROID_NDK}
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}
  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
  -G${CMAKE_GENERATOR})

# Dependency.
ExternalProject_Add(eigen
  HG_REPOSITORY https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen
  HG_TAG 3.2.10
  CMAKE_ARGS ${ANDROID_CMAKE_ARGS})

# Main project that depends on Eigen.
ExternalProject_Add(main
  DEPENDS eigen
  SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main
  CMAKE_ARGS ${ANDROID_CMAKE_ARGS})
```

Here are relevant parts of my app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: did you have som log from gradle ? Maybe CMake configuration has error(s) thus compilation is not triggered ?

Comment: That was my first thought, but gradle doesn't report seem to report any errors. Is there a particular log file that would be helpful?

Comment: did you ever have any luck?