# CMake imported library not included in Gradle aar output

Tags: android, gradle, cmake

In an Android project that loads a C library (mylib.so, which includes a JNI API already), I have a CMakeLists.txt that [import the prebuilt library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries), as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#using_prebuilt_libraries), like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(ImportMyLib)

set(MYLIB_PREBUILT_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../src/build/arm64/src")

add_library(mylib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(mylib
                      PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                      "${MYLIB_PREBUILT_PATH}/libmylib.so")
```

I did print `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../src/build/arm64/src` and checked that `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../src/build/arm64/src/libmylib.so` does exist.

However, `libmylib.so` is not included in the resulting `.aar`, and I don't understand why.

My `build.gradle` does include the CMakeLists.txt above, like so:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098718/build-cmake-externalproject-with-gradle), except that it seems there that there was a need to add an `IMPORTED` target (because of the `ExternalProject_Add`), whereas here I'm trying to import an already built library.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had missed [this part of the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#jniLibs):

> If you want Gradle to package prebuilt native libraries that are not used in any external native build, add them to the src/main/jniLibs/ABI directory of your module.
> Versions of the Android Gradle Plugin prior to 4.0 required including CMake IMPORTED targets in your jniLibs directory for them to be included in your app.
> [...]
> If you are using Android Gradle Plugin 4.0, move any libraries that are used by IMPORTED CMake targets out of your jniLibs directory to avoid this error.

Moving `mylib.so` to `src/main/jniLibs/ABI` does work indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly request `libmylib.so` to be included:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        targets "mylib" # matches add_library(mylib SHARED IMPORTED)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I get "Could not find method targets() for arguments [mylib] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.CmakeOptions$AgpDecorated.", but I can't see what I'm missing there. Really I use the CMakeLists.txt above. Actually it fails before it reaches `add_library` in my CMakeLists (I added a `message(FATAL_ERROR "something")` at the beginning of the file and it's not showing)

Comment: Also I can't find it in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/Cmake

Comment: Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829357/specify-targets-in-externalnativebuild-of-the-build-gradle-file-no-signature-o, I put it in `defaultConfig { externalNativeBuild { cmake` and now it goes further to "Unexpected native build target mylib. Valid values are:". Not sure why valid values are empty, though :/.

Comment: Indeed, `targets` belong to a different clause, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64829814/192373