# How to include/use latest version of Opus codec in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, opus

A complete novice question here. I am pretty familiar with programming in C/C++ on Linux environments. However, I have no experience whatsoever with Android environment, let alone when it comes to making an application with C for Android platforms.
I need to use opus codec in my application but it is not present in the default libraries of Android NDK. How can I add it?

Some sources on internet talk about `Android.mk` files. I am using the most recent version of Android Studio and there is no .mk files, only Cmake files.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/google/prefab/issues/44#issuecomment-593900740), it's as easy as

```
 implementation "com.vcpkg.ndk.support:opus:1.3.1"
```

There are tons of tutorials and examples of how to integrate native code in an Android app. Generally this requires a Java (or Kotlin) wrapper and some JNI code on the C side. Consider also consuming the opus codec via ffmpeg (e.g. [mobile-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) library).

Comment: I managed to build `opus` from this github repo: https://github.com/xiph/opus with only CMake. When I tried to build `opus-1.3.1` sourcecode from mozilla repository with Cmake, it was complaning that configuration failed. However, this github repo worked out of the box. I don't know whether it is up-to-date since it doesn't state any version number.

Comment: [Officially](https://opus-codec.org/development/), https://github.com/xiph/opus is a mirror of their [master repository](https://gitlab.xiph.org/xiph/opus.git), so you should feel good.